# compute difference between each and every element in a row and report as a single column using r?

Tags: r

I have a vector that I have created from grouped data:

```
sitesMODE
FT         KM         KO         LN         LY 
16.840000  32.230769   8.846154 237.000000  57.923077
```

I want to find the difference of each value to every value and ULTIMATELY report it in a single object or column so that I can plot it.

I will reproduce the data here(albeit in matrix form):

```
siteMODE <- matrix(c(16.84, 32.23, 8.84, 237.00, 57.92), 1, 5, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(siteMODE) <- c("FT", "KM", "KO", "LN", "LY")
```

I know that I can use:

```
diffMODELY <- abs(siteMODE - siteMODE[[5]])
```

to find the difference between the expressed column/element `[[n]]` so that:

```
diffMODELY 
FT        KM        KO        LN        LY 
41.08308  25.69231  49.07692 179.07692   0.00000
```

My question is now, how can I do this without having to create an object like `diffMODELY` for every column's/element's difference? AND how can I report the results into as a single object or column in a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

```
DIFF <- sapply(1:ncol(siteMODE), function(i) abs(siteMODE - siteMODE[i]))
DIFF[upper.tri(DIFF)]
 [1]  15.39   8.00  23.39 220.16 204.77 228.16  41.08  25.69  49.08 179.08
```

The `sapply` part computes the differences you want, but it gives you a matrix, since you want the resulting differences into a vector you may want to chose either the upper triangular matrix elements or the lower ones, that's why I applied `upper.tri` function to select just the upper triangular elements and the final result is a vector.

Comment: @XNSTT if this answer meets your needs you can check it as the correct answer by cliking in the green tick mark right below the scoring mark

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `sapply`:

```
res = sapply(siteMODE, function(x) abs(x - siteMODE))
> res
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,]   0.00  15.39   8.00 220.16  41.08
[2,]  15.39   0.00  23.39 204.77  25.69
[3,]   8.00  23.39   0.00 228.16  49.08
[4,] 220.16 204.77 228.16   0.00 179.08
[5,]  41.08  25.69  49.08 179.08   0.00
```

adding names:

```
colnames(res) = colnames(siteMODE)
rownames(res) = colnames(siteMODE)
> res
       FT     KM     KO     LN     LY
FT   0.00  15.39   8.00 220.16  41.08
KM  15.39   0.00  23.39 204.77  25.69
KO   8.00  23.39   0.00 228.16  49.08
LN 220.16 204.77 228.16   0.00 179.08
LY  41.08  25.69  49.08 179.08   0.00
```

Create a nice flat data structure:

```
require(reshape)
res_flat = melt(res)
# Eliminate duplicates
res_flat = res_flat[melt(upper.tri(res))$value,]
> res_flat
   X1 X2  value
6  FT KM  15.39
11 FT KO   8.00
12 KM KO  23.39
16 FT LN 220.16
17 KM LN 204.77
18 KO LN 228.16
21 FT LY  41.08
22 KM LY  25.69
23 KO LY  49.08
24 LN LY 179.08
```

Comment: Hiemmstra, thank you this is also elegant, a general equation regarding 'melt()'  - will this remove any duplicate, if there were some existing other than the zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the data as vector and then using the base `outer` function, yields the same result in a single step:

```
y<- c(16.84, 32.23, 8.84, 237.00, 57.92)
> abs(outer(y,y, `-`))
   [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
[1,]   0.00  15.39   8.00 220.16  41.08
[2,]  15.39   0.00  23.39 204.77  25.69
[3,]   8.00  23.39   0.00 228.16  49.08
[4,] 220.16 204.77 228.16   0.00 179.08
[5,]  41.08  25.69  49.08 179.08   0.00
```